# Units of Translated IFC files has changed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Recently (week 22),we noticed that translated IFC files have a different unit than previous versions.

`viewer.model.getUnitString()`

We use the BIM360 docs translation so we don't know if anything changed there. Previously every IFC file translated to a unit in "ft", regardless of the originated software or settings.

Currently it is in the originated IFC unit (which is obviously more correct).

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BIM360 will use native length units from the IFC file now when uploading a new file that there is no existing version in Docs, as I know. We will share more details later. Please stay tuned with us.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, any idea how to know the units prior to loading the IFC model.

Comment: You can get that by calling [GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties?objectid=<ModelRootId>](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/). The units value is under `properties > Item > Unit`. The `ModelRootId` is usually 1.

Comment: can we get te units without using the Model Derivative API?

Comment: While playing with Forge Viewer, it calls Model Derivative API internally as well, so I don't think there is a way w/o Model Derivative API.